# FileNotFoundException when using getExternalStoragePublicDirectory

Tags: android, filenotfoundexception, android-file, android-external-storage

I've this code for downloading a file from the net. It works fine with phones that have SD cards, but I've tested it on a phone that doesn't have an SD card and I got the following error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException /storage/emulated/0/Movies/65656s5d.mp4 open failed :ENONET (no such file or directory)
```

This is my code in `doInBackGround`:

```
InputStream input = null;
OutputStream output = null;
HttpURLConnection connection = null;
try {
    URL url = new URL(sUrl[0]);
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.connect();

    // expect HTTP 200 OK, so we don't mistakenly save error report
    // instead of the file
    if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        return "Server returned HTTP " + connection.getResponseCode() + " "
                + connection.getResponseMessage();
    }

    // this will be useful to display download percentage
    // might be -1: server did not report the length
    int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

    // download the file
    input = connection.getInputStream();

    long number = (long) Math.floor(Math.random() * 9000000000L) + 1000000000L;
    String destPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES)
            + File.separator+number + ".mp4";
    output = new FileOutputStream(destPath);

    byte data[] = new byte[4096];
    long total = 0;
    int count;
    while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
        // allow canceling with back button
        if (isCancelled()) {
            input.close();
            return null;
        }
        total += count;
        // publishing the progress....
        if (fileLength > 0) // only if total length is known
            publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
        output.write(data, 0, count);
    }
    return "ok";
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.v("this",e.getMessage());
    return e.toString();
} finally {
    try {
        if (output != null)
            output.close();
        if (input != null)
            input.close();
    } catch (IOException ignored) {
        Log.v("this",ignored.getMessage());
        return ignored.toString();
    }

    if (connection != null)
        connection.disconnect();
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: That device runs Android 6.0?

Comment: `this code for downloading a file from the net.` Irrelevant. Your code tries to create a file on the file system.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `getExternalStorageDirectory`. Check the docs for details: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html

Answer (score -1):

`Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES)` has no effect even device does not have sd card, it will always be there. please check your file, is it exist(using exists method in `File` class)?